# What's the chance of pulling a perfect deck?

Tags: probability

What is the chance of pulling 6 cards in the correct order?

The game I play gives you 3 cards at random to play out of my 6 card deck to start with. From the 3 open cards given you pick one to start your game. Next turn, you get another card at random added to the 2 already pulled (the first on is in play) so you have 3 cards again to chose from for you next move.

What is the chance of pulling the cards in the perfect order, say 1,2,3,4,5,6 in this case? They're all different cards.

Comment: Do you want to be able to play a perfect game (i.e. $1$ on the first turn, $2$ on the second, and so on) or do you want to pull the cards in the stated order? The difference being if you want the latter, you must pull $6$ as your last card, while for the former $6$ could be one of your first cards pulled and then you leave it in your hand until the very end.

Comment: Hi Ari, thx for your reply!

The former would be the case. The 6 could be pulled initially and played last.

Answer (score 1):

1 must be among the first three.
2 must be among the first three non-1 cards.
3 must be among the first three non-12 cards.
These are independent, so multiply them together.

Comment: That's a nice way of looking at it $-$ much simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

We can look at this problem as looking for the probability of having a favorably ordered deck from the start (before you are dealt three cards). A favorable deck is simply one which will allow you to win the game.

Obviously $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is a favorably ordered deck, but less obviously $1,6,3,2,4,5$ is also a favorably ordered deck. Why is this favorable? Your initial hand contains $1,6,3$ from which you play $1$ and draw $2$, which you play and draw $4$, then you play $3$ from you initial hand and draw $5$. Thus your hand now has $4,5,6$, which you play in order and win.

The question is, how to find the number of such decks. Clearly $1$ must be one of the first three cards, or you would always lose. What about $2$? Well, you could have $2$ in your hand initially or your could draw it after playing $1$. So $2$ must be one of the first four cards in the deck (three go to your hand, one is drawn after round one), in order to win. The same applies to $3$, it must be part of your hand initially or drawn on one of the two draws before round three. So $3$ must be among the first five cards in the deck. After round three you have picked up all six cards and, assuming you've played $1,2,3$ you have $4,5,6$ left, thus the last card in the deck doesn't matter.

A favorable deck results when $1$ is one of the first three cards, $2$ one of the first four, and $3$ one of the first five. The actual calculations are some basic combinatorics that I'll leave to you.

Comment: Not so basic, I would say.

Comment: 27.78% chance and in the case of a 5 card deck it would be 40%.

Comment: Michael's answer seems right to me, and I make it $\frac36 \times \frac35 \times \frac34 = \frac{9}{40} = 22.5\%$.

Comment: @TonyK, Michael's answer and my answer are equivalent, however I calculate the same answer as Lame Tyant. How did you arrive at your calculations?

Comment: @Ari: My comment contains my calculation explicitly. It follows Michael's answer to the letter. How did _you_ calculate your answer?

Comment: @TonyK Probability $1$ is in the first three: $\frac{3*5!}{6!}=\frac{3}{6}$, $2$ in the first four is $\frac{4*5!}{6!}=\frac{4}{6}$, and for $3$ in the first five, $\frac{5*5!}{6!}=\frac{5}{6}$. $\frac{3}{6}*\frac{4}{6}*\frac{5}{6}\approx 27.78%$.

Comment: No, the probability that $2$ is in the first four is changed by the fact that $1$ is in the first three. Michael's answer is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see. So my solution overcounts. Thank you Tony.